# ajuda com EventEmmiter

Tags: javascript, javascript-eventos, observer-pattern

**Evente Emmiter**

```
const Emmiter = {
eventos:{},
on(event,cb){
    console.log(event);
    Emmiter.eventos[event] = Emmiter.eventos[event] || [],
    Emmiter.eventos[event].push(cb)
},
emitir(event,...params){
    console.log('##  EMITINDO EVENDO :',event);
    if(event in Emmiter.eventos === false){return}else
    Emmiter.eventos[event].forEach((e)=>{
        e(...params);
    })
}


}
export {Emmiter}
```

**Gerar JsonWebToken**

```
import jwt from 'jsonwebtoken'
import { Emmiter } from './Emmiter.js';
const secret = 'chaveSecreta'
 function createToken(){
    Emmiter.on('security:gerar:token',gerar);

    function gerar(obj,timer){
        var token = jwt.sign(obj,secret, {
            expiresIn:(60 * timer) 
          });
          console.log(obj);
         return token;
    }}
export{createToken}
```

**INDEX.JS**

```
import createToken from "./Token.js";
import {Emmiter} from "./Emmiter.js"
createToken();
let token = Emmiter.emitir("security:gerar:token",{id:0,nome:"pedro"},5);
console.log(token)
```

quando executo o index.js
a resposta é undefined
pelo console.log()
alguem poderia me ajudar a resolver isso?

Answer (score 0):

**como ninguem quis me ajudar ou não tinha o conhecimento necessario, vou responder**

**o problema estava no Emmit.js abaixo segue o codigo corrigido!**

```
  const Emmiter = {
    eventos:{},
    resposta:'',
    on(event,cb){
        console.log(event);
        Emmiter.eventos[event] = Emmiter.eventos[event] || [],
        Emmiter.eventos[event].push(cb)
    },
    emitir(event,...params){
        console.log('##  EMITINDO EVENDO :',event);
        if(event in Emmiter.eventos === false){
            console.log('esse evento não existe');
            return false;
        }else{
        Emmiter.eventos[event].forEach((e)=>{
           Emmiter.resposta = e(...params);
        })
        return Emmiter.resposta;
    }
    }
}
export {Emmiter}
```

**seguindo o conselho do bot**
a correção foi a seguinte

```
  emitir(event,...params){
        console.log('##  EMITINDO EVENDO :',event);
        if(event in Emmiter.eventos === false){
            console.log('esse evento não existe');
            return false;
        }else{
        Emmiter.eventos[event].forEach((e)=>{
           Emmiter.resposta = e(...params);// aqui estava certo
           //estava dando erro por que eu estva retornando aqui
//o resultado da função
        })
        return Emmiter.resposta;//fiz uma variavel e respondi aqui
    }
    }
}
export {Emmiter}
```

ai tudo se resolvel e funcionol perfeitamente
se não intendeu copia e cola no vs code e testa so assim a gente aprende

Comment: Como está escrito atualmente, sua resposta não é clara. Por favor, pode [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, que ajudarão outras pessoas a entender como isso resolve a pergunta feita. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).